# Wait for global user object before initializing other modules

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngx-translate

I have a method `load()` which is ran in a global authorization service that gets a user object from the server. This method is run with APP_INITIALIZER. The method looks as follows:

```
load(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT + ApiConstants.AUTHENTICATE).map(response => response.json() as User).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
        this.user = data;
        this.translate.use(this.user.language);
    });
}
```

I am using ngx-translate to get the language of the user on the server and then load the corresponding translation file. My translation module looks as follows:

```
export class AppTranslationModule {
constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private auth: AuthService) {
    translate.addLangs(["en", "de"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang("de");
    translate.use(this.auth.user.language);
 }
}
```

The problem is that the user object from the auth service is still undefined when doing the `translate.use(this.auth.user.language)`. How can I make everything wait for the user object to get loaded from the server before doing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make a function (In AppTranslationModule) that does this:

```
translate.addLangs(["en", "de"]);
translate.setDefaultLang("de");
translate.use(this.auth.user.language);
```

Call load() of Auth service from your component and seek response. After getting response, call this function that does translation. Remove translation tasks from constructor. Rather, call a function [After getting user response] that performs these tasks.